# pep8 compliance with long json dictionary lookup?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, pep8

Using a character length of 79, how would someone formulate a command such as:

```
return method_returning_json()['LongFieldGroup1']['FieldGroup2']['FieldGroup3']['LongValue']
```

If I move the lookups to the next line, such as:

```
return method_returning_json()\
    ['FieldGroup1']['FieldGroup2']['FieldGroup3']['Value']
```

pep8 complains about "space before [" since there are several tabs. However, if I move the second/third/etc group to a newline it does the same thing.

I know I can add the `# noqa` tag to the end of the line but I am hoping there is a better way.

Comment: You may want to break lookup to intermediate variables (`o1 = method_returning_json()['FieldGroup1']` and `o2 = o1['FieldGroup2']['FieldGroup3']['Value']`, to give an example). It'll work best if `o1` and `o2` can have meaningful names and acts as a commentary to data. Besides that there's not much you can do.

Comment: I also wouldn't get _too_ obsessive about PEP8. It's a great guideline and I'm very glad that most Python developers follow it most of the time, but IMO the version you suggest with a backslash after the method call is quite readable, as long as there aren't _too_ many `['groups']['of']['square']['brackets']`. IMO the `pep8` tool complaining isn't necessarily enough to change your code. Be a bit flexible if it does actually improve readability.

Comment: Outside of the standard library itself and docstrings, I think most people consider a line length of approximately 100 characters to be reasonable. That said, one should try to tame the extreme outliers, regardless of your chosen threshold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use implicit line continuation that occurs inside parentheses:

```
return (method_returning_json()
          ['LongFieldGroup1']
          ['FieldGroup2']
          ['FieldGroup3']
          ['LongValue'])
```

(You may need to adjust the actual indentation to make the `pep8` tool happy.)

You can even use the indexing brackets themselves to allow implicit line continuation, although I don't really find any of the variations particularly readable.

```
# Legal, but probably not desirable.
# At the very least, pick one style and be consistent; don't
# use a variety of options like I show here.
return method_returning_json()[
         'LongFieldGroup1'][
         'FieldGroup2'][
         'FieldGroup3'
         ][
         'LongValue'
         ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Quoting [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

> A Foolish Consistency is the Hobgoblin of Little Minds
>
> One of Guido's key insights is that code is read much more often than it is written. The guidelines provided here are intended to improve the readability of code and make it consistent across the wide spectrum of Python code. As PEP 20 says, "Readability counts".
>
> A style guide is about consistency. Consistency with this style guide is important. Consistency within a project is more important. Consistency within one module or function is the most important.
>
> However, know when to be inconsistent -- sometimes style guide recommendations just aren't applicable. When in doubt, use your best judgment. Look at other examples and decide what looks best. And don't hesitate to ask!
>
> In particular: do not break backwards compatibility just to comply with this PEP!
>
> Some other good reasons to ignore a particular guideline:
>
> When applying the guideline would make the code less readable, even for someone who is used to reading code that follows this PEP.
>
> To be consistent with surrounding code that also breaks it (maybe for historic reasons) -- although this is also an opportunity to clean up someone else's mess (in true XP style).
>
> Because the code in question predates the introduction of the guideline and there is no other reason to be modifying that code.
>
> When the code needs to remain compatible with older versions of Python that don't support the feature recommended by the style guide.

In my opinion (and it's just an opinion) there are times such as yours in which breaking the line makes the code harder to read, and so this may be a reasonable time to ignore the line-length guideline.

Having said that, if you really want to keep the line length under 79, one
way might be to actually split the command into separate lines:

```
some_json = method_returning_json()
key1 = 'FieldGroup1'
key2 = 'FieldGroup2'
key3 = 'FieldGroup3'
return some_json[key1][key2][key3]['Value']
```

This is not as succinct as the single line approach, but each line is shorter. Which is the lesser evil is for you to judge.